# Use the dif function to obtain the difference with several lags without specifying the number of lags

Tags: sas

I want a new data set in which the variable y is equal to the value in the n row minus the lags values.
The original data set:

```
data test;
    input x;
    datalines;
20
40
2
5
74
;
run;
```

I used the **dif** function, but It returns the difference with a one lag:

```
data want;
    set test;
    y = dif(x);
run;
```

And I want:

```
_n_ = 1  y = 20
_n_ = 2  y = 40 - 20 = 20
_n_ = 3  y = 2 - (40 + 20) = -58
_n_ = 4  y = 5 - (2 + 40 + 20) = - 57
_n_ = 5  y = 74 - (5 + 2 + 40 + 20) = 7
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `lag()` or `dif()`.  Just make another variable to retain the running total.

```
data want ;
  set test;
  y=x-cumm;
  output;
  cumm+x;
run;
```

I kept the extra column and output the values before updating the running total to make it clearer what value was used in the calculation of Y.

```
Obs     x      y    cumm

 1     20     20      0
 2     40     20     20
 3      2    -58     60
 4      5    -57     62
 5     74      7     67
```

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution (thanks to Longfish for suggestions):

```
data want;
    set test;
    retain total 0;
    total = total + x;
    y = x - coalesce(lag(total), 0);
run;
```

Comment: Your solution could be simplified further.  I'd also recommend not using key words as column names (i.e. SUM).

 `data want;
 set test;
 _tot+x;
 y = x-coalesce(lag(_tot),0);
 drop _tot;
 run;`

Comment: Thanks! Coalesce fits perfectly here. I renamed sum, but kept all the variables for transparency.